# How to use Table Valued Function against CTE created Data

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I am just wanting to work with a Table Valued Function and test it against data built up by a simple CTE however I'm not able to figure out how to get the Table Valued Function to 'see' the CTE.  What am I missing here?

```
/* The below shows that I can SELECT the CSVField from my CTE CSVData */
WITH CSVData AS
(
    SELECT 'a,b,f,hello,yup' as CSVField
)
SELECT CSVField FROM CSVData
;


/* This Works and produces a table of the CSV Values */
SELECT * FROM dbo.Split('a,b,f,hello,yup', ',')


/* Does NOT Work: The below for whatever reason the TVF can't see the CTE as if it's not in Scope or for some other reason */
WITH CSVData AS
(
    SELECT 'a,b,f,hello,yup' as CSVField
)
SELECT c.* FROM dbo.Split(CSVData.CSVField, ',') c
;
```

> Table Output Example

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this as

```sql
    WITH CSVData AS
    (
        SELECT 'a,b,f,helloWorld,YesSir' as CSVField
    )
    SELECT c.*
    FROM dbo.Split( (SELECT CSVField FROM CSVData) , ',') c
    ;
```